# How to get rid of duplicated lines in SQL Cross Join Query result?

Tags: sql

I have a PERSON table:

[image: PERSON]

To get the list of persons who have a difference between their ages less than 5 years, I try:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON p1
CROSS JOIN PERSON p2
WHERE p1.psn_id <> p2.psn_id 
  AND p1.psn_age - p2.psn_age <= 5;
```

So I got:

[image: RESULT]

As you can see, the second line is the same as the first. My question is how to get rid of the duplicated line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON p1 
CROSS JOIN PERSON p2 
WHERE 
    p1.psn_id < p2.psn_id
AND 
    ABS(p1.psn_age - p2.psn_age) <= 5;
```

Comment: That doesn't actually work, and even when the syntax is fixed, it produces the same result as the `cross join`.

Comment: You're right, but I'm pretty sure I've done this before and left join was involved, I'm looking through my files right now, see if I find something... I'll come back and let you know :-)

Comment: Yeah, it produces the same result

Comment: fixed with p1.psn_id<p2.psn_id

Comment: and ABS(p1.psn_age - p2.psn_age) <= 5

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select
    *
from
    PERSON a
    inner join
    PERSON b on a.psn_id < b.psn_id and abs(a.psn_age - b.psn_age) <= 5;
```

It will put the older person on the left. If for whatever reason you'd prefer it the other way around, change `a.psn_age - b.psn_age` to `b.psn_age - a.psn_age`.

Update, I have verified this by adding three new people of ages 87, 84 and 50, to ensure that the 87 and 84 match each other, and the 50 does not match anything.

Comment: That way I get rid of each of the first and second line, but I want to get rid only of one of them!

Answer (score 2):

Not only the second line is essentially a duplicate of the first one, but also the third and fourth lines in your output do not satisfy the requirement, because the difference between those people's ages is greater than 5.

I believe it should be enough specify that the difference should not be negative:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON p1
CROSS JOIN PERSON p2
WHERE p1.psn_id <> p2.psn_id
  AND p1.psn_age - p2.psn_age BETWEEN 0 AND 5
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Left Join if I understood correctly:

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON p1
LEFT JOIN PERSON p2
on p1.psn_id < p2.psn_id 
  AND  ABS(p1.psn_age - p2.psn_age) <= 5;
```

Comment: I don't remember if there's a single SQL product supporting `LEFT JOIN` without `ON`. Anyway, if you look at the [history of @elcodedocle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26191119/revisions), you'll see that your present suggestion was also his first one (and it didn't work, as can be seen by the comments).

Comment: @Andriy M. Yes I forget to add "ON" clause and I have just updated my answer, Thanks for that. in elcodedocle's answer he has user cross join and I think solution is just to use Left Join